# Genysys Java PSDK - setup Eventhandler for web application

Tags: java, genesys

I am setting up Genysys PSDK to connect to tServer and listen to events using handler. I have created

> MessageHandler

to receive messages but looks like its not working somehow. [Genesys Document](https://docs.genesys.com/Documentation/PSDK/latest/Developer/EventHandling) states that we need to implement AsyncInvoker in order to receive events.

Can someone help me how can I setup AsyncInvoker when working with spring boot application?

> Important:
> You need to know that your event-handling logic will be executed by using the protocol invoker. Please set the invoker appropriate for your application needs.

Answer (score 0):

I was opening tserver connection before setting handler.
Setting

```
      tserver.setMessageHandler(new MessageHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onMessage(Message arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                System.out.println("Message Handler" + arg0.toString());
            }
        });
```

before opening connection worked for me.